# How can I access the values of an inner block in Gutenberg?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying to build a custom block for Gutenberg. It is a carousel and uses child blocks (images). I'm trying to find a way to find out how many image-blocks were created inside to block so I can create slides for the carousel accordingly.

In order to do that, I was thinking about taking the image url from each image block and store it in an array so then I can just map through the array to create each slide, but I have no idea how to access the url value from the child block.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read the (very tiny) documentation on the [getBlock function in the Block Editor Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/data-core-block-editor/#getBlock). You should use the `withDispatch` higher order component to feed your components (blocks) with actions.

```
withDispatch( ( dispatch, ownProps, registry ) => {

  return {
    updateEditable( isEditing ) {
      const { clientId, setAttributes } = ownProps;
      const { getBlockOrder, getBlock } = registry.select( 'core/block-editor' );

      //get all innerBlockIds
      const innerBlockIds = getBlockOrder( clientId );
      innerBlockIds.forEach( ( innerBlockId ) => {
        console.log( getBlock( innerBlockId ) );
      } );
    },
  };
} )
```

To play around with the WordPress data module, that offers data about the editor or blocks to the client, you can also make use of the `wp.data`-Module. In the backend view of Gutenberg editor, you can, for example, go to a browser console and type `wp.data.select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlock(<blocks-client-id>)` to test what the function does.

You can also have a look in the Gutenberg GitHub repository. [Core Blocks also use these function, for example in columns](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/columns/edit.js).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parent innerBlocks using the code below.

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { useSelect } = wp.data;
const { store: blockEditorStore } = wp.blockEditor;

/**
 * Block Edit Component
 */
const Edit = (props) => {
    const { clientId } = props;
    const innerBlocks = useSelect(
        (select) => select(blockEditorStore).getBlock(clientId).innerBlocks,
    );

    console.log( innerBlocks ); // This will log all the inner blocks on your browser console
};
```

If you also need to access them via PHP render, you can check this article : https://jeffreycarandang.com/how-to-access-innerblocks-attributes-within-the-parent-block-on-the-wordpress-gutenberg-editor/